# discord.py How to check if user is on server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to check if the user is on the server. Please help me
[image: I mean function like this]

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image.

Comment: `on_ready` is a coroutine that gets called when the bot goes online and is thus executed *once* at startup. Are you sure you want to put it there and not in a command? Because it is not written in a command it is missing server and user context. You want to "check" but you haven't explained how and when you want to check. The code you posted only opens up more questions.

Comment: @TinNguyen Yes, I'm sure. I want to check if the user is on the server, if yes, then do something. And I want to check if the bot is ready, that's why I have it in on_ready function.

Comment: @TinNguyen I mean, Can I get list of members and servers, then check if the member is on the server? I don't really know how to do that :(

Comment: Please don't add tags to your question that have nothing to do with your question. There was no need to include discord.js and discord.net

Answer (score 6):

You can search a guild by ID for a member by ID using [`discord.Guild.get_member()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member), which returns a `discord.Member` object if found, and `None` if not found.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = bot.get_guild(ID_OF_GUILD) # find ID by right clicking on server icon and choosing "copy id" at the bottom
    if guild.get_member(ID_OF_MEMBER) is not None: # find ID by right clicking on a user and choosing "copy id" at the bottom
        # the member is in the server, do something #
    else:
        # the member is not in the server, do something #
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to define a guild by name or id, then fetch all members on a defined guild
Here's your code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   guild = await bot.get_guild(ID) #fetch by ID
   guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name="Foo") # fetch by name
   for i in guild.members:
      print(i)
```