# In discord.py how do I check if a member is on the server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my bot to check if a member is on the server or not.
I'm only asking this because I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003512/discord-py-how-to-check-if-user-is-on-server) and it always returns None, no matter what.

Here's my code so far:

```py
@bot.command()
async def membercheck(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(my_server_id)
    if guild.get_member(member) is not None:
        await ctx.send("he on server")
    else:
        await ctx.send("he not on server")
```

Ideally my code should work so that you input a User ID and the bot checks if the user is on the server.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: yes, i have all intents enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning `None` always cause you're passing a `discord.Member` object to `Guild.get_member` instead of an int.

```py
@bot.command()
async def membercheck(ctx, member: discord.User):
    guild = bot.get_guild(some_id)

    member = guild.get_member(member.id)

    if member is None:
        await ctx.send('Member is not in the server')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Member is in the server')
```

Also it's better if you use `UserConverter` as `MemberConverter` is going to raise `MemberNotFound` error when it can't get the member

EDIT

```py
@bot.command()
async def membercheck(ctx, id: int):
    guild = bot.get_guild(some_id)

    member = guild.get_member(id)

    if member is None:
        await ctx.send('Member is not in the server')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Member is in the server')
```

Comment: first off, thank you so much for your help. the command works when the user is in the server. however, even if i do use discord.User it raises the error UserNotFound.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're trying to get a user that isn't in any of the guilds the bot is in, you can try typehinting it to an int, and using that to get the member. I'll edit my answer.